# Is there a way to have multiple legend colour text in a bokeh chart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I am working on an simple bar chart in bokeh, with the titanic dataset. I find the framework to be extremely flexible, however there is one last chart element i would like to control: the individual colours of the legend text.

Looking at the reference doc here ->

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#legends

I can see how to adjust the colour of the legend text (as a whole), however i would like to be able to colour of "First" to match the same colour as my column colour (i.e. #3a6587), and "Second" and "Third" as colour #aeb3b7

I include my sample code below:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("bar_colormapped.html")

ticket = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
counts = [84.15, 20.66, 13.68]


# .var width parameter controls the width of the columns
# We can add the colours to the barchart as part of a palette list.
# Note the width to height ration should be 1.618:1 ish ;-)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(ticket=ticket, counts=counts))

p = figure(x_range=ticket, plot_height=480, plot_width= 647, toolbar_location=None, 
    title="Average Titanic Fare, by Class")
p.vbar(x='ticket', top='counts', width=0.7, source=source, legend="ticket",
       line_color='white', fill_color=factor_cmap('ticket', 
        palette=['#3a6587', '#aeb3b7', '#aeb3b7'], factors=ticket))


# Removes the chart gridlines (i.e.. removes the chart clutter)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

# change just some things about the x-axes
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Class Type"
p.xaxis.axis_line_width = 2
p.yaxis.major_label_text_color = "#aeb3b7"
p.xaxis.axis_line_color = "#aeb3b7"


# change just some things about the y-axes
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Average Fare Price (in Pounds)"
p.yaxis.axis_line_width = 2
p.yaxis.major_label_text_color = "#aeb3b7"
p.yaxis.axis_line_color = "#aeb3b7"
p.yaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"


# Set the range of the chart
p.y_range.start = 0
p.y_range.end = 90


# Remove the border. Set the width to 0 does not work so we need 
# to set to 0.1 to make it less visible.
p.outline_line_width = 0.1

# Set attributes for the chart title
p.title.text_color = "black"
#p.title.text_font = "times"
#p.title.text_font_style = "italic"
p.title.align = "center"


# Set the position and orientation of the legend and remove 
# the legend border
p.legend.orientation = "vertical"
p.legend.location = "top_right"
p.legend.border_line_width = 0.1


show(p)
```

A mockup of a proposed image is included below:

[image: Propsed Legend Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.0.4 legends only support a single text color across all entries. No one has ever asked about this before, but it would be reasonable to make a feature request on GitHub about it (especially if you would be interested in helping contribute).

Comment: using the above code the legend text remains black for all three legend items. I am using the latest version of bokeh 1.0.4

Comment: Sorry I actually missed that you wanted to control the *text*. That is not currently configurable to be variable across entries.

Comment: Not sure why this was unaccepted. As the project leader for Bokeh, I can assure you that the only answer, at least for the time being, is "that is not possible".

Comment: your comments are entirely reasonable. I've accepted the answer. I'll also drop over to the bokeh repo and i can discuss further some enhancements suggestions I have (especially around Gestalt theory), which I think could add extra value to bokeh.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of a colored text in a bokeh chart legend:

```
from bokeh.io import *
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.plotting import figure

names = ["Jim","Bob","Assia"]
colors = ["red","blue","green"]

# filename for saving the plot in current folder
plot_filename = "plot_colored legend.html"

# legend1 = Legend( label_text_color=colors[k],items=[
fig = figure(plot_width=900, plot_height=450)
items = []
for i in range(3):                                  # horizontal or vertical   # above, below, left, right or center           row=  Abstand,  
    #                                                                                                                                           column höhe oben
    fig.add_layout(Legend( 
                          label_text_color=colors[i], 
                                  items=[(names[i], 
                                      [fig.circle(i,i,color=colors[i], size=20)])],
                          border_line_alpha = 0.0,
                          location=((5 + (i * -85) )- i**i  ,380- i *25 )),
                   'right')

output_file(plot_filename)
print ('The plot has been saved under the file name: "{}"'.format(plot_filename))
show(fig)
```

[bokeh colored legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnWM1.jpg)